# Is reference lost?

Tags: actionscript

First a bit of code:

var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000);
mc.graphics.beginFill(0xFF00000)
mc.graphics.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
var array:Array = [mc];

this.addChild(array[0]);

mc = new MovieClip();

this.removeChild(array[0]);
this.addChild(array[0]);

I would expect it to update reference held in array and add empty MovieClip to the stage. Is that wrong assumption then?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Changing which movie clip mc refers to does not change which movie clip array[0] refers to.  It still refers to the old one.  Instead, change the last line to `this.addChild(mc);` or add another line which says `array[0] = mc;` between the removeChild and the addChild which follows it.